# Ansible: Unable to create /etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact, permission denied

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin, ansible-facts, ansible-inventory

I am following [this blog](https://albertomolina.wordpress.com/2015/10/13/openshift-3-on-openstack/) to install OpenShift Origin V3 on OpenStack using ansible. But I am getting error

> "Could not create fact file: %s, error: %s" % (filename, ex)
>   **main**.OpenShiftFactsFileWriteError: Could not create fact file: /etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact, error: [Errno 13] Permission
>   denied: '/etc/ansible/facts.d'

The target system is CentOS and I can do passwordless sudo on the target systems. I even added in `/etc/sudoers`

> centos All=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

to all the nodes and also on the system from which I am running ansible.

From the system I run ansible, I tried executing as sudo, as root but same results.

I am not sure where it faces permission denied, I mean on the host or the target systems.

**Ansible hosts:**

```
[OSEv3:children"]
masters
nodes

[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=centos
ansible_sudo=true
#ansible_ssh_user=root

product_type=openshift
deployment_type=origin

[masters]
192.168.144.132 openshift_public_hostname=master.novalocal openshift_ip=10.0.1.163 openshift_public_ip=192.168.144.132

[nodes]
192.168.144.128 openshift_public_hostname=node1.novalocal openshift_ip=10.0.1.164 openshift_public_ip=192.168.144.128 openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}" 
192.168.144.129 openshift_public_hostname=node2.novalocal openshift_ip=10.0.1.165 openshift_public_ip=192.168.144.129 openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
```

**Ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
hostfile = ansible_hosts
remote_user = centos
host_key_checking = False
```

Below is the log:

```
TASK: [openshift_facts | Ensure PyYaml is installed] ************************** 
ok: [192.168.144.132] => (item=PyYAML)

TASK: [openshift_facts | Gather Cluster facts] ******************************** 
failed: [192.168.144.132] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449035570.03-273189812167365/openshift_facts", line 6355, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449035570.03-273189812167365/openshift_facts", line 1222, in main
    openshift_facts = OpenShiftFacts(role, fact_file, local_facts, additive_facts_to_overwrite)
  File "/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449035570.03-273189812167365/openshift_facts", line 999, in __init__
    self.facts = self.generate_facts(local_facts, additive_facts_to_overwrite)
  File "/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449035570.03-273189812167365/openshift_facts", line 1013, in generate_facts
    local_facts = self.init_local_facts(local_facts, additive_facts_to_overwrite)
  File "/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449035570.03-273189812167365/openshift_facts", line 1194, in init_local_facts
    save_local_facts(self.filename, new_local_facts)
  File "/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449035570.03-273189812167365/openshift_facts", line 924, in save_local_facts
    "Could not create fact file: %s, error: %s" % (filename, ex)
__main__.OpenShiftFactsFileWriteError: Could not create fact file: /etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact, error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ansible'
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
Shared connection to 192.168.144.132 closed.


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/config.retry

192.168.144.132            : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I have no prior experience with ansible therefore I am unable to debug more.

Comment: That error indicates that the openshift_facts module is unable to write to the /etc/ansible/facts.d directory on the remote host.

Generally, I've only seen this error when run as a non-root user without sudo, but from the inventory snippets you provided, that does not appear to be the case here.

If you manually ssh into 192.168.144.132 as the centos user and attempt to run the following command: `sudo touch /etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact`. If that fails, then whatever is causing root to be unable to wright to /etc/ansible/facts.d needs to be resolved before continuing.

Comment: @detiber `sudo touch /etc/ansible/facts.d/openshift.fact` gives **No such file or directory** error, probably because facts.d folder does not exist. But I can create a random file in `/etc/ansible` folder.

Comment: What version of ansible are you using?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what would cause the facts.d directory to not be created, since we are using os.makedirs to create the directory (and parent directories) if they do not exist: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/42232eb59cc3c6ae5d4733b6655add0aff23217b/roles/openshift_facts/library/openshift_facts.py#L909-L925

Comment: @detiber I lost access to the machine I was working on, but I installed it from yum repository yesterday and also clone ansible from github. So, it is the latest available in repo and github.

Comment: Could you provide the full inventory file that you are using and the full command line you are using for invoking ansible-playbook?

Comment: @detiber I have posted the inventory file in another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072391/ansible-openshift-install-failing-with-assertion-openshift-common-deployment-ty). If you want I can update this question as well. 
I created `ansible.cfg` and `ansible_hosts` file outside the openshift-ansible (created from git clone) directory and from there I ran **ansible-playbook openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/config.yml**

Comment: @detiber Can you please confirm the target OpenStack version for this playbook. My OpenStack version is **IceHouse**. BTW I have update the question with the full inventory file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution seems very trivial to this. I found it on google group of ansible.

Just need to add

```
sudo = true 
sudo_user = root
```

in the ansible.cfg file.

At least this error is gone but I encountered new error.

**EDIT**
As suggested in comments below, sudo_user must be root, therefore, changed the anser accordingly.

Comment: setting sudo_user doesn't seem correct, that is supposed to be the user that ansible acts as, which in this case *should* be the default of root.

Comment: Do you mean it should not be added and by default it takes true & root values?

Comment: sudo = true should not really be needed since your inventory is setting ansible_sudo on the OSEv3 group, but it doesn't do any harm to have it in the ansible.cfg file.

Comment: sudo_user = centos is telling ansible to sudo *to* the centos user when executing tasks, which would not have the proper permissions for installing packages or modifying many of the files needed during the configuration steps.